# SQL Server : how to get the database engine type?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to script an object from SQL Server, but I get the following error:

> SQL Azure Federation objects are not supported in SQL Server 2012.
>   To script the SQL Azure federation objects change the target database engine type to SQL Azure Database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo).

Is there a query I can run that shows me the current database engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.  Should work in SQL Azure as well as stand-alone SQL Server

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

or

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```